# JQuery autocomplete on select link to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I have the following jQuery autocomplete

```
   $(function() {
    $("#my_ac").autocomplete({
        source: [
            {
                value: "/Tom-Hanks",
                label: "Tom Hanks",
                description: "Actor",
                image: "hanks.png"
            },
            {
                value: "/Termionator-2",
                label: "Termionator 2",
                description: "Movie",
                image: "terminator.png"
            }
        ],
        minLength: 1
    }).data( "autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        var inner_html = '<a><div class="list_item_container"><div class="image"><img src="' + item.image + '"></div><div class="label">' + item.label + '</div><div class="description">' + item.description + '</div></div></a>';
        return $( "<li></li>" )
            .data( "item.autocomplete", item )
            .append(inner_html)
            .appendTo( ul );
    };
});
```

When selecting a label, I want to load a new page url i.e: selecting "Tom Hanks" to link to the page `/Tom-Hanks`

Comment: can you provide a js fiddle?

Comment: Your `<a>` tag heeds an `href=""`

Comment: your <a> has no href attributes... or maybe it's because Termionator is offended...

Comment: how can I add a link by hitting enter. If I hit enter now it is just returning the label in the field and doesn't follow the link(value)